# Ordernar array por uma propriedade

Tags: php, array, classificação

Estou tentando ordenar um array por uma propriedade especifica(peso), encontrei algumas possíveis soluções porém não funcionaram para o meu caso, alguém saberia dizer em que parte estou fazendo algo errado ou uma outra saída para minha necessidade?

**Como estou tentando realizar a ordenação:**

```
function ordenaPorPeso($a, $b) { 
    if($a->peso == $b->peso){ return 0 ; }
    return ($a->peso < $b->peso) ? -1 : 1;
} 

$arrayPaginas = array(  
            array("url" => "teste1.php", "peso" => 10),
            array("url" => "teste2.php", "peso" => 5),                      
            array("url" => "teste3.php", "peso" => 8),
            array("url" => "teste4.php", "peso" => 4),
            array("url" => "teste5.php", "peso" => 9)                     
            );

usort($arrayPaginas, 'ordenaPorPeso');

foreach($arrayPaginas as $pagina){

    echo $pagina["url"]. " - " . $pagina["peso"] . "<br /><br />";

}
```

**Saída:**

```
teste5.php - 9

teste4.php - 4

teste3.php - 8

teste2.php - 5

teste1.php - 10
```

Comment: O correto é `$a['peso']` e `$b['peso']`

Comment: Acho que isso deve te ajudar [Array Multisort Exemple](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php#100534)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro está na função. Cada elemento de `$arrayPaginas` é um array, e não um objeto.

Faça a seguinte correção:

```
function ordenaPorPeso($a, $b) { 
    if ($a['peso'] == $b['peso']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a['peso'] < $b['peso']) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Ou, numa versão mais concisa:

```
function ordenaPorPeso($a, $b) { 
    return (($a['peso'] != $b['peso']) ? (($a['peso'] < $b['peso']) ? -1 : 1) : 0);
}
```

Comment: Vou testar assim que voltar para o escritório Rodrigo, mas acredito que seja a resposta correta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão 7 do PHP existe o *spaceship operator* que auxilia nesta tarefa.

- [Pra que serve os "spaceship operator" <=> do PHP7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87231/5878)

Ele substitui as condições (ou o ternário) utilizado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9794/5878):

```
$arrayPaginas = [  
    ["url" => "teste1.php", "peso" => 10],
    ["url" => "teste2.php", "peso" => 5],                      
    ["url" => "teste3.php", "peso" => 8],
    ["url" => "teste4.php", "peso" => 4],
    ["url" => "teste5.php", "peso" => 9]                     
];

usort($arrayPaginas, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['peso'] <=> $b['peso'];
});

print_r($arrayPaginas);
```

O resultado será, como esperado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => teste4.php
            [peso] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => teste2.php
            [peso] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => teste3.php
            [peso] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => teste5.php
            [peso] => 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [url] => teste1.php
            [peso] => 10
        )

)
```