# Pra que serve os "spaceship operator" <=> do PHP7?

Tags: php, operadores, php-7

Estava dando uma olhada nas [New Features do PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) e me deparei com um operador, que nunca tinha visto em nenhuma linguagem de programação. O Manual do PHP demoninou ele de `Spaceship Operator`.

Vou demonstrá-los abaixo o que vi:

```
echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
echo 1 <=> 2; // -1
echo 2 <=> 1; // 1
```

Não sei se eu entendi direito, mas me parece que ele faz a mesma coisa que o [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php).

- Afinal, simplificadamente, qual é a finalidade desse operador?
- Quais são as vantagens obtidas ao utilizá-lo?

Comment: Tava esperando essa pergunta :D

Comment: E estava esperando que eu fosse perguntar?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O operador [`<=>`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) é utilizado para fazer comparações combinadas.

- Retorna *0*  se os valores de ambos os lados são **iguais**.
- Retorna *1*  se o valor à **esquerda** é maior.
- Retorna *-1*  se o valor à **direita** é maior.

Exemplo:

```
echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
echo 3 <=> 4; // -1
echo 4 <=> 3; // 1
```

A vantagem em usar o operador `<=>` é que ele não se restringe a um determinado tipo, enquanto a [função `strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php) limita-se a *strings*.

Em linguagens como [*Ruby*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html), [*Perl*](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node37.html) e [*Groovy*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_spaceship_operator) esse operador também está presente.

Comment: Vai ser legal ver isso funcionando com `arrays`. Mudará a vida de `array_sort` e afins :)

Answer (score 10):

A documentação já diz bem o que é:

> O operador *spaceship* é usado para comparar duas expressões. Ele retorna um inteiro menor do que, igual a, ou maior que zero quando $a é respectivamente menor do que, igual a, ou maior que $b. As comparações são realizadas de acordo com as regras de comparação de tipos habitual do PHP.

Melhorando o exemplo da documentação:

```
echo -1 <=> -1; // 0
echo -10 <=> 2; // -1
echo 20 <=> 1; // 1
```

A principal vantagem é ser independente de tipos.

Comment: +1 pela _Melhorando o exemplo da documentação_. Aquele exemplo dava a entender que poderia retornar `-2`, `-5`. Não por causa da explicação, mas por causa do código - que é a primeira coisa que olho, quando não entendo a explicação.

Answer (score 6):

De uma versões pra cá, o php parece estar trocando algumas funções por operadores. Por exemplo, [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) que faz o cálculo de exponenciação pode ser trocado por (`**`); [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)  pode ser trocado por [Spread Operator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87234/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-do-operador-usado-no-php-5-6). Esses dois estão disponíveis a partir do [php 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

A espaçonave faz quase a mesma coisa que a função [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php), entretanto se aplica a outros tipos, e não somente a strings.

Comment: Me permita adicionar que `**` é operador de exponenciação. Gosto de saber dos nomes desses carinhas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `**` é negrito, não sabia se ia sair normal, por isso falei dois astericos haha.

Answer (score 5):

Em geral as linguagens usam uma função. A função que você citou compara *strings*, já o operador `<=>` trabalha com vários tipos onde esta forma de comparação é possível.

Antes o PHP sequer tinha uma função que fazia isto com números.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta de @stderr, você pode utilizá-lo em funções que trabalham com ordenação de dados.

Veja o caso da função usort, que recebe como segundo parâmetro uma função que deve retornar -1, 0 ou 1 como resultado da ordenação de 02 parâmetros recebidos.

```
usort($durations, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a <=> $b;
});
```

isso é o mesmo que

```
usort($durations, function ($a, $b) {
if($a < $b) {
    return -1;
}
if($a > $b) {
    return 1;
}

return 0;
});
```