# Ordenar números de telefone em uma string

Tags: php, regex

Tenho alguns números de telefones, móveis e fixos, em um banco de dados, usei a função `implode()`para junta-los numa mesma string, ficando desse jeito:

```
(11) 3333-4353  (11) 98000-2222 (11) 3027-5555 (11) 97000-0333
```

O que quero fazer é ordena-los com preferência para celulares, ou seja, após o DDD (xx) os números que tiverem 9,8,7 na frente serão ordenados no início, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: nesse exemplo que você deu, como ficaria ordenados? "(11) 97000-0333 (11) 98000-2222 (11) 3027-5555 (11) 3333-4353" ou simplesmente poderia ser "(11) 98000-2222 (11) 97000-0333 (11) 3333-4353  (11) 3027-5555"?

Comment: Como só usei exemplos de com iniciais 3 e 9, os dois números com 9 ficariam na frente e resto atrás

Comment: Só seguindo a ordem dos 9,8,7 já está bom, o resto é indiferente.

Comment: não acho que regex seja o melhor jeito para resolver isso, talvez alguma função que pega o segundo numero e ordena?

Comment: o php já não ordenaria isso para você usando ORDER BY DESC ?

Answer (score 5):

Olá, utilize a função [usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php), com ela você define uma função que valida a ordem, o retorno desta função deve ser `-1` ou `1`. Ela e aplicada em arrays para realizar comparação.

Veja como ficaria:

```
<?php

$telefones = array(
    "(11) 3333-4353",
    "(11) 98000-2222",
    "(11) 3027-5555",
    "(11) 97000-0333",
);

function sortNumber($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $b);
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($telefones, 'sortNumber');

print_r($telefones);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (11) 98000-2222
    [1] => (11) 97000-0333
    [2] => (11) 3333-4353
    [3] => (11) 3027-5555
)
```

Um exemplo de utilizar esta aplicação dentro de uma classe com exemplo completo:

```
<?php

class Telefones
{
    // Variável com os telefones
    private $telefones = array();

    // Construtor para enviar os telefones
    public function __construct($telefones)
    {
        if( is_array($telefones) )
        $this->telefones = $telefones;
    }

    // Funcão para ordenar
    public function ordernarTelefones()
    {
        $telefones = $this->telefones;      
        usort($telefones, array($this, 'sortNumber'));
        $this->telefones = $telefones;

        return $this;
    }

    // Função para resgatar os dados
    public function pegarTelefones()
    {
        return $this->telefones;
    }

    // Função auxiliar customizada com regra de ordenar
    private function sortNumber($a, $b)
    {
        $a = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $a);
        $b = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $b);
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }

}

$array = array(
    "(11) 3333-4353",
    "(11) 98000-2222",
    "(11) 3027-5555",
    "(11) 97000-0333",
);

$telefones = new Telefones($array);

print_r(
    $telefones
        ->ordernarTelefones()
        ->pegarTelefones()
);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (11) 98000-2222
    [1] => (11) 97000-0333
    [2] => (11) 3333-4353
    [3] => (11) 3027-5555
)
```

Comment: Como usaria num escopo de classes? "$this->sortNumber", aspas mesmo?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, você pode utilizar assim: usort($telefones, array($this, 'sortNumber'))

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 coloquei um exemplo de utilização com classe.

Answer (score 3):

Se está usando php pode usar ORDER BY DESC

exemplo com MySQLi

```
    $sql=("SELECT coluna FROM Tabela ORDER BY coluna DESC"); 

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tels .=$row["cel_cli"]. " ";
    }

    echo $tels;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não há informação da origem desses dados, se for via banco de dados a resposta do @Leo Caracciolo seja suficiente. Em casos gerais, como onde está lendo do arquivo pode usar o `usort`, como já indicado. Entretanto, se o DDD não importa poderá omiti-los:

---

```
$telefones = [
    '(11) 3333-4353',
    '(11) 98000-2222',
    '(11) 3027-5555',
    '(11) 97000-0333',
    '(12) 99999-9999',
    '(12) 88888-8888',
    '(13) 11111-1111'

];


usort($telefones, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtr(substr($a, 5), ['-' => '']) <=> strtr(substr($b, 5), ['-' => '']);
});
```

Isso irá resultar em:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "(11) 3027-5555"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "(11) 3333-4353"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "(13) 11111-1111"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "(12) 88888-8888"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "(11) 97000-0333"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "(11) 98000-2222"
  [6]=>
  string(15) "(12) 99999-9999"
}
```

A ideia é bem simples, [segundo o Wikipedia todos os DDDs tem exatamente 2 dígitos e partem do 11](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discagem_direta_a_dist%C3%A2ncia), portanto usamos:

```
substr($valor, 5);
```

Para que obtenhamos apenas o que for a partir do espaço, ou seja o primeiro número do telefone em diante (* na verdade ele irá obter qualquer coisa no 5º caractere, não importa se é um número telefônico ou não*).

Depois usamos:

```
strtr($valor, ['-' => ''])
```

Para remover o `-`, o uso do `strtr` para o `str_replace` é apenas performance, ele tende, nestes casos, ser um pouco mais rápido, além de preferencia pessoal mesmo, mas pode usar qual preferir.

Assim usamos o spaceship operator, [leia mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87231/pra-que-serve-os-spaceship-operator-do-php7), ele retorna qual o valor é maior, um pouco similar com o `strcmp`, porém ele apenas retorna `1`, `0` ou `-1`.

---

Se quiser listar o contrário use a matematica básica do `* (-1)`, isso irá fazer com que `1` seja `-1` e o mesmo o contrário, assim ordenando de maneira decrescente:

```
usort($telefones, function ($a, $b) {
    return (strtr(substr($a, 5), ['-' => '']) <=> strtr(substr($b, 5), ['-' => ''])) * (-1);
});
```

---

*Em relação a resposta do @Bruno Rigolon esta deve ser um pouco mais rápida, [compare isto](https://3v4l.org/PBLUX) e [isto](https://3v4l.org/inGg0) em sua maquina.*

> /!\ Ele não trará os dados, por isso ele irá "confiar" em qualquer valor, portanto se houver `(aa) 123c5-abc3`, o que não é um número válido, ele não terá nenhuma ação diferente.