# Pesquisa em Array com condições

Tags: php

Tenho um **Array** de registros:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HANDLE] => 1
            [Z_GRUPO] => 
            [EMPRESA] => 1
            [FILIAL] => 1
            [DATAINICIO] => 2018-01-01 
            [CONSUMO] => 2
            [VEICULO] => 82
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HANDLE] => 2
            [Z_GRUPO] => 
            [EMPRESA] => 1
            [FILIAL] => 1
            [DATAINICIO] => 2018-02-01
            [CONSUMO] => 2.5
            [VEICULO] => 82
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HANDLE] => 3
            [Z_GRUPO] => 
            [EMPRESA] => 1
            [FILIAL] => 1
            [DATAINICIO] => 2018-03-01
            [CONSUMO] => 3
            [VEICULO] => 82
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [HANDLE] => 4
            [Z_GRUPO] => 
            [EMPRESA] => 1
            [FILIAL] => 1
            [DATAINICIO] => 2018-02-01
            [CONSUMO] => 3.5
            [VEICULO] => 102
        )

)
```

---

#### Pergunta:

Gostaria de **pesquisar no Array** tendo como referência uma **DATA e um VEICULO**.

---

**Exemplo:**

Qual é o **CONSUMO** do `VEICULO 82` na `DATA 10/02/2018`?

Se fosse um banco de dados, seria simplesmente isso:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM VEICULOCONSUMO
WHERE VEICULO = 82
AND DATAINICIO <= '10/02/2018'
ORDER BY DATAINICIO DESC
```

O retorno correto seria: `2.5`

Como o registro foi feito em `10/02/2018`, então a data anterior mais recente ou igual, era `[1][DATAINICIO] => 2018-02-01`.

O "X" da questão é como puxar o CONSUMO referente a DATA e VEICULO, onde a **DATA é igual a DATAINICIO OU a anterior mais recente**.

Comment: `DATAINICIO` é uma `string` ? Esses dados vem de onde, do banco de dados ? Se for o caso não é mais facil trazer logo o que você quer, com a consulta que exemplificou ?

Comment: @Isac a data vem nesse formato que eu até estou achando estranho [sqlsrv_fetch_array retorna campo datahora como objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316572/sqlsrv-fetch-array-retorna-campo-datahora-como-objeto)... Vem de um BD mas eu trago outros registros referentes, então não tem como fazer associação na query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar os registros que possuem veículo igual a 82 e data início menor ou igual a 2018-02-10 com a função `array_filter`:

```
$filtrados = array_filter($registros, function ($registro) {
    return ($registro['VEICULO'] == 82) and ($registro['DATAINICIO'] <= '2018-02-10');
});
```

Ordenar o resultado pela data de início, da maior para a menor:

```
usort($filtrados, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['DATAINICIO'] <=> $b['DATAINICIO'];
});
```

E, como quer apenas um registro, pegar o último valor do array:

```
$final = array_pop($filtrados);
print_r($final);
```

Ficando:

```
Array
(
    [HANDLE] => 2
    [Z_GRUPO] => 1
    [EMPRESA] => 1
    [FILIAL] => 1
    [DATAINICIO] => 2018-02-01
    [CONSUMO] => 2.5
    [VEICULO] => 82
)
```

Que é o registro mais recente, com data menor ou igual a 2018-02-10.

Comment: Woss, não pode somar. Seria assim: na data `10/02/2018` foi feito um documento pelo veículo `82`, então quero saber qual era o consumo daquele veículo nesse dia que foi feito esse documento (no caso, isso é uma média de consumo km/L).

Comment: É está meio complicado de entender! rs... por isso até colei o exemplo do `select` que é exatamente aquilo que eu queria fazer no array... Preciso pegar o consumo em `10/02/2018` OU o anterior mais recente...

Comment: Não entendi aqui: `array_filter($registros, function ($registro) {`... `$registros` é meu Array correto!? E o `$registro` seria o que?

Comment: @RBZ Cada item do seu array...

Comment: Perfeito, manda bem demais cara! ... só ali no `usort` que está `$B` (maiúsculo) e chamando `$b` (minúsculo)... e a comparação está `<=>`, funcionou com `<=`.

Comment: O operador <=> é o [spaceship](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87231/5878), criado justamente para isso.

Comment: Mas ele dá erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in`

Comment: Versão do PHP, então.

Comment: Então deve ser só na 7. Estou reparando aqui, e o `usort` organizou certinho, mas o `array_pop` pega o último, então pega o errado. Vou olhar como funcionam para acertar...

Comment: Definido assim no `PHP 5` ... `return $a['DATAINICIO'] >= $b['DATAINICIO'];`

Comment: cara tu é um deus, era exatamente o que eu tava precisando, vlwzao