# Tipo Object em PHP

Tags: php, operadores, cast, array-associativo, objetos

Estou praticando alguns códigos em PHP, quando me deparo com esse:

```
<?php
$a = (object) ["a" => "b"];
$b = (object) ["a"  => "c"];

$y = $a <=> $b;
echo $y;
$v=[1,2,3] <=> [1,2,3];
echo $v;
$a= (object) ["a" => "b"];
$b = (object) ["a" => "b"];
echo $a <=> $b;
echo ($y == -1)? 1:0;
?>
```

Como faz muito tempo que não pratico PHP minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. Por que as saídas dos três primeiros `echo`  estão sendo, respectivamente,
   `-1,0,0`?
2. Como realizo essa conversão `["a" => "b"]` de tipo para objeto?
3. Qual o nome disso `<=>`? operador de comparação? Igualdade? Busquei
   no `php.net` não encontrei nada sobre isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Por que as saídas dos três primeiros `echo` estão sendo, respectivamente, `-1,0,0`?

De acordo com a definição do operador de comparação (veja abaixo) são os resultados esperados. No primeiro o operando da esquerda é menor, ou seja, a letra `b` é menor que a letra `c`. Nos demais os valores são idênticos, portanto o resultado é 0.

> Como realizo essa conversão `["a" => "b"]` de tipo para objeto?

Fez da forma correta, ainda que com utilidade questionável.

> Qual o nome disso `<=>`? operador de comparação? Igualdade? Busquei no `php.net` não encontrei nada sobre isso.

Veja: [Pra que serve os "spaceship operator" <=> do PHP7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87231/101).

```
$a = (object)["a" => "b"];
$b = (object)["a"  => "c"];
$y = $a <=> $b;
echo $y;
$v=[1,2,3] <=> [1,2,3];
echo $v;
$a= (object)["a" => "b"];
$b = (object)["a" => "b"];
echo $a <=> $b;
echo ($y == -1)? 1:0;
var_dump($a);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/prujou). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tbxhjdeh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/CastObject.php).