# Como ordenar um array por dois indices diferentes?

Tags: php, array

Olá a todos recentemente escrevi esse código, onde ele vai mostrar a lista de alunos na array por order decrescente de score e no fim mostra o top 3. Este é o código:

```
<?php

$Turma = array(

array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("nome" => "Joao","score" => "500", "time" => "3" ),
array("nome" => "Miguel", "score" => "125", "score" => "8" ),
array("nome" => "Daniela", "score" => "105", "time" => "7" ),
array("nome" => "Joana", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "275", "time" => "4" ),
array("nome" => "Francisco", "score" => "300", "time" => "9" ),
array("nome" => "Ines", "score" => "650", "time" => "2" ),
array("nome" => "Dionisio", "score" => "101", "score" => "10" ),
array("nome" => "Ricardo", "score" => "200", "score" => "8" ),
array("nome" => "Fabio", "score" => "201", "score" => "11" ),
array("nome" => "Tiago","score" => "50", "score" => "13" ),
array("nome" => "Carolina", "score" => "150", "time" => "5" ), 
array("nome" => "Rui", "score" => "130", "time" => "3" ),
array("nome" => "Luisa", "score" => "1000", "time" => "1" ),

);


 usort($Turma, function($a,$b){
    return $b["score"] - $a["score"];


});

 foreach($Turma as $key => $value) {
    
    $position = $key + 1;
    
    echo "{$position}: {$value['nome']} : {$value['score']} <br>";

}






echo "<br>";
echo "WINNERS!! <br> ";

foreach($Turma as $key => $value) {
    
    $position = $key + 1;

    if ($position < 4) {
        echo "{$position}: {$value['nome']} : {$value['score']} <br>";
    }

    
}
```

Agora é me pedido para ordernar os alunos caso haja empate de score o mais rápido ganha, gajo haja empate em tempo e score temos de ordenar alfabeticamente.

Comment: Boa tarde. Poste o código, ao invés de postar a imagem. Clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/482010/edit).

Comment: Para comparar strings use [`strcmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php) ou [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcasecmp.php). A diferença entre elas é que na primeira a comparação não distingue maiúsculas de minúsculas

Comment: Qual é a versão usada do PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro detalhe é que seu `array`está com alguns erros. Você duplicou a chave `score` aqui:

```
array("nome" => "Ricardo", "score" => "200", "score" => "8" ),
```

Segundo detalhe é que, pra fazer essa comparação, como foi dito, pode usar a função `strcmp` ou `strcasecmp`, porém eu preferi utilizar uma abordagem nova, introduzida nas versões mais novas do php: O [spaceship operator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87231/pra-que-serve-os-spaceship-operator-do-php7).

```php
usort($Turma, function ($a, $b) {

    $resultado = $b['score'] <=> $a['score'];

    return $resultado === 0 ? $b['time'] <=> $b['time'] : $resultado;
});
```

O operador `<=>` vai comparar os valores, podendo retornar `-1`, `0` ou `1`. Quando retorna `0`, é porque os valores são iguais. Então, utilizei uma condição ternária para que, quando for igual a `0`, a comparação se der pela coluna `time`.

#### Versão corrigida do seu `array`

```
$Turma = array(

array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("nome" => "Joao","score" => "500", "time" => "3" ),
array("nome" => "Miguel", "score" => "125", "time" => "8" ),
array("nome" => "Daniela", "score" => "105", "time" => "7" ),
array("nome" => "Joana", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "275", "time" => "4" ),
array("nome" => "Francisco", "score" => "300", "time" => "9" ),
array("nome" => "Ines", "score" => "650", "time" => "2" ),
array("nome" => "Dionisio", "score" => "101", "time" => "10" ),
array("nome" => "Ricardo", "score" => "200", "time" => "8" ),
array("nome" => "Fabio", "score" => "201", "time" => "11" ),
array("nome" => "Tiago","score" => "50", "time" => "13" ),
array("nome" => "Carolina", "score" => "150", "time" => "5" ), 
array("nome" => "Rui", "score" => "130", "time" => "3" ),
array("nome" => "Luisa", "score" => "1000", "time" => "1" ),

);
```

#### Teste no `ideone`

- https://ideone.com/O0lFYc