# Ordernar array em PHP por valor de uma key (Com os campos com valores inteiros)

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Tenho um array multidimensional do tipo

> ```
> echo "<pre>";
> print_r($order_info);
> exit();
> ```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3227
            [seller_id] => 27
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3249
            [seller_id] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3040
            [seller_id] => 27
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 1240
            [seller_id] => 1
        )
```

Gostaria de organizá-lo de modo ASCENDENTE pelo seller_id

ou seja
eu gostaria que ele ficasse da forma:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3249
            [seller_id] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 1240
            [seller_id] => 1
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3227
            [seller_id] => 27
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 3040
            [seller_id] => 27
        )
```

Ou seja eu gostaria de agrupá-los pelo seller_id (que não é outro array)

o que eu tenho que fazer com meu array `$order_info`?

Comment: [Ordernar array por uma propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9791/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que isto resolva seu problema.

```
function ordenarPorSellerID($a, $b) { 
    return (($a['seller_id'] != $b['seller_id']) ? (($a['seller_id'] < $b['seller_id']) ? -1 : 1) : 0);
}
```

Comment: Ao invés do ternário, utilizar o *spaceship* é mais simples: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344648/5878